# they send invitations to

Tags: meaning, quantifiers

a. I got an invitation from their company and thought they really liked me. Then I found out that they send invitations to anyone.

b. The fact that you received samples of their chocolates doesn't mean anything. They send them to anyone.

I don't think 'anyone' can be replaced with 'everyone' in the above sentences. They send them more or less haphazardly, but they can't send them to everyone.

I think 'anyone' sounds a bit odd in these sentences, but actually the sentences are fine.

Am I correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: to just anyone would work.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **everyone** refers to all the members of a group, and **anyone** refers to some or all the members of a group. **Anyone** can also be used to add emphasis.

In your examples, you can use either word. They are interchangeable. I personally prefer **everyone** because I think there's context implied in your examples. Take the first (I made a couple of other suggestions, too):

> (a) *Since* I got an invitation from *the* company, *I* thought they really liked me. Then I found out that they send invitations to **everyone**.

"The group" that you're talking about comes from the conversation and is implied in the sentence. But it's probably something like:

> ... Then I found out that they send invitations to **everyone** [*who interviews there*].

**Everyone** is a better choice because you mean *all* members of the group, or every person who interviewed at the company.

**Anyone** would typically be used for emphasis, and probably needs the future tense:

> ... Then I found out that they *will* send invitations to **anyone**.

---

Here's the second example:

> b. The fact that you received samples of their chocolates doesn't mean anything. They send them to **everyone**.

Again, either is fine but I prefer **everyone** because I think there's implied information about what the group is, and that you mean every person in the group. For example:

> ...They send them to **everyone** [who buys roses].

You can use **anyone** for empahsis:

> ... They will send them to absolutely **anyone**!

---

FWIW, there are some cases where **anyone** and **everyone** are not interchangeable because the meaning changes slightly. For example, suppose you ask this question of a group of 10 kids:

> Does anyone want pizza for dinner?

The answer is yes if 1 or more people want pizza.

> Does everyone want pizza for dinner?

The answer is yes only if all 10 want pizza.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both your sentences are correct and natural English. And you're right that "anyone" means people that were not specially selected. "Anyone" cannot be replaced with "everyone".

Comment: I disagree. They are completely interchangeable in the sentences provided.

Comment: @swmcdonnell You think, "*They send invitations to **everyone***" means exactly the same as "*They send invitations to **anyone***"? Like, there's no difference in the implied number of invitations sent out?